# How to find out if an email address starts with something and ends with a domain

Tags: php, strpos

Take this email for example

```
$email = "outlook_75AA07B2DF4B8074@outlook.com";
```

I need to use php to find out if an email starts with `outlook_` AND ends with `@outlook.com`. Since `75AA07B2DF4B8074` will always be different. I've got the beginning but not sure how to get the end as well.

```
if (strpos($email, 'outlook_') === 0) {

}
```

Comment: Might be easier using Regular Expressions

Comment: `strpos(strrev($email), strrev('@outlook.com')) === 0;`

Comment: Maybe `^outlook_.*?@outlook[.]com$` You tagged `strpos` is that required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_match('/^outlook_.*@outlook\.com$/', $email);`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `strpos` with a negative offset to search for the trailing `@outlook.com`. Since that has a fixed length of 12 characters, you can use an offset of `-12` to `strpos` to only look for `@outlook.com` in the last 12 characters; thus it will only match if those characters are exactly `@outlook.com`. For example:

```
$email = "outlook_75AA07B2DF4B8074@outlook.com";
if (strpos($email, 'outlook_') === 0 && strpos($email, '@outlook.com', -12) !== false) {
    echo "outlook email address\n";
}
```

Comment: The negative offset is an approach I hadn't considered.

Comment: @user3783243 I think it's probably more efficient than regex. `substr($email, -12) == '@outlook.com'` would also work well but I decided to stick with `strpos` for consistency